# Check length between two characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string, loops

So I've been working on this coding challenge for about a day now and I still feel like I haven't scratched the surface even though it's suppose to be Easy. The problem asks us to take a string parameter and if there are exactly 3 characters (not including spaces) in between the letters 'a' and 'b', it should be true.

Example: `Input: "maple bread"; Output: false // Because there are > 3 places`

```
Input: "age bad"; Output: true // Exactly three places in between 'a' and 'b'
```

Here is what I've written, although it is unfinished and most likely in the wrong direction:

```
function challengeOne(str) { 
let places = 0;
 for (let i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if (str[i] != 'a') {
     places++
   } else if (str[i] === 'b'){    
   }
 }
console.log(places)
}
```

So my idea was to start counting places after the letter 'a' until it gets to 'b', then it would return the amount of places. I would then start another flow where if 'places' > 3, return false or if 'places' === 3, then return true.

However, attempting the first flow only returns the total count for places that aren't 'a'. I'm using console.log instead of return to test if it works or not.

I'm only looking for a push in the right direction and if there is a method I might be missing or if there are other examples similar to this. I feel like the solution is pretty simple yet I can't seem to grasp it.

Edit:

I took a break from this challenge just so I could look at it from fresh eyes and I was able to solve it quickly! I looked through everyone's suggestions and applied it until I found the solution. Here is the new code that worked:

```
function challengeOne(str) { 
  // code goes here  
str = str.replace(/ /g, '')
let count = Math.abs(str.lastIndexOf('a')-str.lastIndexOf('b'));
if (count === 3) {
  return true 
} else return false

}
```

Thank you for all your input!

Comment: Given the examples, it sounds like there should be exactly 2 characters between the letters, not 3? If `age bad` should be `true`, removing spaces gets to `ageb` - `ge` is 2 characters, not 3

Comment: The question is not so clear though, what if there is `aabab`. Should it be `true` or `false`

Comment: But with `maple bread`, there's  `brea`, with exactly 2 characters between a `b` and an `a`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more efficient approach - simply find the indexes of the letter `a` and `b` and check whether the absolute value of subtracting the two is 4 (since indexes are 0 indexed):

```js
function challengeOne(str) {
  return Math.abs(str.indexOf("a") - str.indexOf("b")) == 4;
}

console.log(challengeOne("age bad"));
console.log(challengeOne("maple bread"));
```

> if there are exactly 3 characters **(not including spaces)**

Simply remove all spaces via [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), then perform the check:

```js
function challengeOne(str) {
  return str = str.replace(/ /g, ''), Math.abs(str.indexOf("a") - str.indexOf("b")) == 4;
}

console.log(challengeOne("age bad"));
console.log(challengeOne("maple bread"));
```

References:

- [`Math#abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)
- [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: This was extremely helpful! I used .lastIndexOf instead but still had the same concept. I should have thought about subtracting the indexes to get the counts in between.

Comment: @JennilTee If it solves your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume spaces *are* counted and your examples seem to indicate this, although your question says otherwise. If so, here's a push that should be helpful. You're right, there are JavaScript methods for strings, including one that should help you find the index (location) of the a and b within the given string.

Try here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods

Comment: Since the OP asked only for a push in the right direction, I didn't give the actual code example for an answer.  Hoping I didn't violate Stack Overflow etiquette in doing this!

Comment: Thank you for this! This actually helped me find exactly what I was looking for. I was using .indexOf but it would show me the index of the initial character so even if the string 'abcde agub' was true it would be false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: This one excludes spaces as in the OP, so the output reflects that. If it is to include spaces, that line could be removed.

```js
function challengeOne(str) {
  //strip spaces
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
  //take just the in between chars 
  let extract = str.match(/a(.*)b/).pop();
  return extract.length == 3
}

console.log(challengeOne('maple bread'));
console.log(challengeOne('age bad'));
```

Comment: Fails with `challengeOne("a_a___b__b")`; not sure whether ok or not though.

Comment: Thank you, I used the replace method since the test cases did not want spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can go recursive:

1. Check if the string starts with `'a'` and ends with `'b'` and check the length
2. Continue by cutting the string either left or right (or both) until there are 3 characters in between or the string is empty.

Examples:

```
maple bread
aple brea
aple bre
aple br
aple b
ple 
le

FALSE

age bad
age ba
age b

TRUE
```

```js
const check = (x, y, z) => str => {
  const exec = s => {
    const xb = s.startsWith(x);
    const yb = s.endsWith(y);
    return ( !s                             ? false
           : xb && yb && s.length === z + 2 ? true
           : xb && yb                       ? exec(s.slice(1, -1))
           : xb                             ? exec(s.slice(0, -1))
                                            : exec(s.slice(1)));
  };
  return exec(str);
}

const challenge = check('a', 'b', 3);

console.log(`
  challenge("maple bread"): ${challenge("maple bread")}
  challenge("age bad"): ${challenge("age bad")}
  challenge("aabab"): ${challenge("aabab")}
`)
```